# Replace NA with sample() by group

Tags: r, random, group-by, dplyr

I would like to gapfill missing data (NA) by sampling from non-NA values from the group that the missing data belongs to.

group = Outlet

Also, if nrows(group) == 1 then draw random values from all groups (e.g. Outlet == ESO0244476).

Here's what I've tried so far:

Sample data

```
> dput(droplevels((example)))
structure(list(LENGTH = c(NA, 45447.4157838775, 161037.71538108, 
78147.8550470324, 7193.48815617057, 1571.95459212405, 18191.381972185, 
20366.2132412031, 10014.987524596, 1403.72511829297, 5651.17842991513, 
6848.03271105711, 8043.32937011393, 8926.65133418451, 5808.44456603825, 
2208.14264175252, 1797.4936747033, 5325.76651327694, 2660.66730207955, 
5844.07912541444, 3956.40473896271, 959.873314407621, 3294.01472360025, 
5221.94864001864, 3781.51913857335, 7811.83819953768, 3387.20323328623, 
5514.92099458441, 5792.54371531706, 5643.98385143961, 15478.916809379, 
8401.66533205217, 7046.25074819247, 2734.73639821402, NA, 62332.3343404513, 
NA, 46563.1214718113, 25590.4020105238, 13015.3682275862, 4984.80432801441, 
NA), NUMPOINTS = c(NA, 0, 8, 5, 2, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 6, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, NA, 
10, NA, 19, 6, 5, 0, NA), CTRY_ = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("WCY_____ES", "WCY_____FR", 
"WCY_____IT"), class = "factor"), Outlet = structure(c(4L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("DSO0045543", "DSO0208527", 
"DSO0213034", "ESO0244476"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-42L), class = "data.frame")
```

Sample code

```
exam %>%
  mutate(nuLENGTH = if_else(CTRY_ == 'WCY_____FR', LENGTH, sample(LENGTH[!is.na(LENGTH) & Outlet == Outlet], 1, TRUE)),
         nuNUMPOINTS = if_else(CTRY_ == 'WCY_____FR', NUMPOINTS, sample(NUMPOINTS[!is.na(NUMPOINTS) & Outlet == Outlet], 1, TRUE)))
```

Within each group I expect the values for `nuLENGTH` and `nuNUMPOINTS` where `CTRY_ != 'WCY_____FR'` to be different between groups as well as within a group, not the same e.g.

```
        LENGTH NUMPOINTS      CTRY_     Outlet    nuLENGTH nuNUMPOINTS
1           NA        NA WCY_____ES ESO0244476   1000.0000           0
2   45447.4158         0 WCY_____FR DSO0213034  45447.4158           0
3  161037.7154         8 WCY_____FR DSO0213034 161037.7154           8
4   78147.8550         5 WCY_____FR DSO0213034  78147.8550           5
5    7193.4882         2 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   7193.4882           2
6    1571.9546         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   1571.9546           0
7   18191.3820         9 WCY_____FR DSO0045543  18191.3820           9
8   20366.2132         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543  20366.2132           0
9   10014.9875         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543  10014.9875           0
10   1403.7251         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   1403.7251           0
11   5651.1784         3 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   5651.1784           3
12   6848.0327         1 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   6848.0327           1
13   8043.3294         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   8043.3294           0
14   8926.6513         6 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   8926.6513           6
15   5808.4446         1 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   5808.4446           1
16   2208.1426         1 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   2208.1426           1
17   1797.4937         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   1797.4937           0
18   5325.7665         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   5325.7665           0
19   2660.6673         1 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   2660.6673           1
20   5844.0791         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   5844.0791           0
21   3956.4047         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   3956.4047           0
22    959.8733         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543    959.8733           0
23   3294.0147         1 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   3294.0147           1
24   5221.9486         2 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   5221.9486           2
25   3781.5191         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   3781.5191           0
26   7811.8382         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   7811.8382           0
27   3387.2032         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   3387.2032           0
28   5514.9210         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   5514.9210           0
29   5792.5437         1 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   5792.5437           1
30   5643.9839         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   5643.9839           0
31  15478.9168         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543  15478.9168           0
32   8401.6653         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   8401.6653           0
33   7046.2507         1 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   7046.2507           1
34   2734.7364         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   2734.7364           0
35          NA        NA WCY_____IT DSO0045543   7046.2507           0
36  62332.3343        10 WCY_____FR DSO0045543  62332.3343          10
37          NA        NA WCY_____IT DSO0045543   3000.0000           0
38  46563.1215        19 WCY_____FR DSO0208527  46563.1215          19
39  25590.4020         6 WCY_____FR DSO0208527  25590.4020           6
40  13015.3682         5 WCY_____FR DSO0208527  13015.3682           5
41   4984.8043         0 WCY_____FR DSO0208527   4984.8043           0
42          NA        NA WCY_____ES DSO0208527   2000.0000          0
```

Comment: What is missing data to you? Your example data.frame doesn't have NAs

Comment: Can you add to your question a partial table with the expected output? I don't see any missing data, and it's not clear to me exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Missing data is now NA.

Comment: your groups is `Outlet` right? You want to replace `NA` in `LENGTH` with random values and  `nuNUMPOINTS` with 0 ? How do you get 1000 in first row when there is only one value in group (`ESO0244476` ) ?

Comment: group = Outlet. I want to replace NA in LENGTH with random values from the same group. I want to do the same NUMPOINTS. If nrows group size == 1 then draw random values from all groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write a function if there is `NA` value in `LENGTH` and number of rows in group is more than 1, select random value from the group excluding `NA` values. If the number of values in group is just 1 then select random value from the entire data excluding `NA` values. We apply the function for both the columns `LENGTH` and `NUMPOINTS`.

```
replace_func <- function(x, y) {
    inds <- is.na(x)
    if (length(x) > 1 & any(inds)) {
     x[inds] <- sample(x[!inds], sum(inds))
     x
    }
    else if(any(inds)) {
       x[inds] <- sample(y[!is.na(y)], 1)
       x
    } else x
}

library(dplyr) 

exam %>%
  group_by(Outlet) %>%
  mutate(nuLENGTH = replace_func(LENGTH, .$LENGTH), 
         nuNUMPOINTS = replace_func(NUMPOINTS, .$NUMPOINTS)) 

#  LENGTH NUMPOINTS CTRY_      Outlet     nuLENGTH nuNUMPOINTS
#     <dbl>     <dbl> <fct>      <fct>         <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1     NA         NA WCY_____ES ESO0244476    7046.          19
# 2  45447.         0 WCY_____FR DSO0213034   45447.           0
# 3 161038.         8 WCY_____FR DSO0213034  161038.           8
# 4  78148.         5 WCY_____FR DSO0213034   78148.           5
# 5   7193.         2 WCY_____FR DSO0045543    7193.           2
# 6   1572.         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543    1572.           0
# 7  18191.         9 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   18191.           9
# 8  20366.         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   20366.           0
# 9  10015.         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543   10015.           0
#10   1404.         0 WCY_____FR DSO0045543    1404.           0
# … with 32 more rows
```

Comment: The ```nuLENGTH``` values for ```Outlet == DSO0045543``` are the same in the output. I was expecting a range of values representative of the distribution - i.e. 2 different values. Also, ```sum(is.na(NUMPOINTS))``` can simply be ```1```

Comment: @user3725599 that is weird. I wrote a function to replace values which should work now. Can you check ?

Comment: Thank you! And in case length > 1 but both are NA then we can change the first ```if``` to 
```x[inds] <- sample(ifelse(is.null(x[!inds]), nrow(exam), x[!inds]), sum(inds), replace = T)```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option with `dplyr`

But as @Ronak said, there is no other observations in the same group to sample from in your first line.

```
example %>% 
  group_by(Outlet) %>% 

  mutate(

    nuLENGTH = case_when(
      is.na(LENGTH) ~ sample(LENGTH,size=1),
      !is.na(LENGTH) ~ LENGTH),

    nuNUMPOINTS = case_when(
      is.na(NUMPOINTS) ~ sample(NUMPOINTS,size=1),
      !is.na(NUMPOINTS) ~ NUMPOINTS))
```

Comment: Excellent! Re @Ronak: 
If nrows group size == 1 then draw random values from all groups